# Call graph of apk using JAVA program

Tags: java, android, dalvik, call-graph, soot

I want to create a JAVA program that takes apk files(present in the computer) as input and than return its call graph as output. 
I want to do it on windows platform and write the program in JAVA

Please suggest some ways to do so. I read about soot, dexpler, jimple but could't find a proper source or beginner friendly source to do so.Please suggest some ways of using soot, to convert apk into jimple code and after that use the same jimple code to generate the call graphs

Please see once again i want to do it on windows platform and write in java

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find the call graph of an apk by soot and dexpler.

Look at here:

https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/soot-infoflow-android/issues/76

I tested it and it works perfectly. Just import the required classes.